# Why is my KeyListener not working after adding buttons to the frame?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keylistener

When I delete `setButton()` and press keys, there are right reactions, but if I add `setButton()`, only button works, there is no reaction for pressing keys, what happens here?

```
public class Sokaban extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton btnBack,btnFirst,btnNext,btnPrev,btnLast,btnSelect,btnMusic,btnReset;
    JComboBox<String> cbMusic;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu mnuOption,mnuSet,mnuHelp;
    JMenuItem miReset,miPrev,miNext,miSelect,miExit,miBack;
    JMenuItem miMusic1,miMusic2,miMusic3,miMusic4,miMusic5;
    JMenuItem miHelp;
    //music file
    String sMusic[] = {
        "eyes on me.mid",
        "guang.mid",
        "nor.mid",
        "popo.mid",
        "qin.mid"
    };
    //game panel
    MyPanel mainPanel;
    public Sokaban(int[][] samplemap){
        super("Game 2017");

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image image = toolkit.getImage("pic/p0.jpg");
        //set icon
        this.setIconImage(image);
        Container c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(null);
        c.setBackground(Color.orange);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("SOKABAN GAME",JLabel.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD,20));
        lblTitle.setBounds(100,40,500,30);
        c.add(lblTitle,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //put buttons
        setButton(c);
        setMenus();

        mainPanel = new MyPanel(samplemap);
        mainPanel.setBounds(60,120,450,450);
        mainPanel.setFocusable(true);
        mainPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
        c.add(mainPanel);

        setSize(720,720);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    //set button
    public void setButton(Container c){
        btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
        btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnFirst = new JButton("First");
        btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnPrev = new JButton("Prev");
        btnLast = new JButton("Last");
        btnSelect = new JButton("Select");
        btnMusic = new JButton("Music");
        JLabel lblMusic = new JLabel("Select Music");
        c.add(lblMusic);

        btnReset.addActionListener(this);
        btnBack.addActionListener(this);
        btnFirst.addActionListener(this);
        btnNext.addActionListener(this);
        btnPrev.addActionListener(this);
        btnLast.addActionListener(this);
        btnSelect.addActionListener(this);
        btnMusic.addActionListener(this);
        //cbMusic.addActionListener(this);

        cbMusic = new JComboBox<String>();
        cbMusic.addItem("default");
        cbMusic.addItem("good");
        cbMusic.addItem("music");
        cbMusic.addItem("choose");
        cbMusic.addItem("column");

        btnReset.setBounds(600,100,80,30);
        btnBack.setBounds(600,150,80,30);
        btnFirst.setBounds(600,200,80,30);
        btnNext.setBounds(600,250,80,30);
        btnPrev.setBounds(600,300,80,30);
        btnLast.setBounds(600,350,80,30);
        btnSelect.setBounds(600,400,80,30);
        btnMusic.setBounds(600,450,80,30);
        lblMusic.setBounds(600, 500, 80, 30);
        cbMusic.setBounds(600, 530, 80, 30);
        c.add(btnReset);
        c.add(btnBack);
        c.add(btnFirst);
        c.add(btnNext);
        c.add(btnPrev);
        c.add(btnLast);
        c.add(btnSelect);
        c.add(btnMusic);
        c.add(cbMusic);

    }


    //set menu
    public void setMenus(){
        mnuOption = new JMenu("Option");
         miReset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
         miPrev = new JMenuItem("Previous");
         miNext = new JMenuItem("Next");
         miSelect = new JMenuItem("Select");
         miExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
         miBack = new JMenuItem("Back");

         mnuOption.add(miBack);
         mnuOption.add(miReset);
         mnuOption.add(miPrev);
         mnuOption.add(miNext);
         mnuOption.add(miSelect);
         mnuOption.addSeparator();
         mnuOption.add(miExit);

         mnuSet = new JMenu("Setting");
         miMusic1 = new JMenuItem("default");
         miMusic2 = new JMenuItem("good");
         miMusic3 = new JMenuItem("music");
         miMusic4 = new JMenuItem("choose");
         miMusic5 = new JMenuItem("column");
         mnuSet.add(miMusic1);
         mnuSet.add(miMusic2);
         mnuSet.add(miMusic3);
         mnuSet.add(miMusic4);
         mnuSet.add(miMusic5);

         mnuHelp = new JMenu("Help");
         mnuHelp.setMnemonic('H');
         miHelp = new JMenuItem("About us...");
         mnuHelp.add(miHelp);

         miBack.addActionListener(this);
         miReset.addActionListener(this);
         miPrev.addActionListener(this);
         miNext.addActionListener(this);
         miSelect.addActionListener(this);
         miMusic1.addActionListener(this);
         miMusic2.addActionListener(this);
         miMusic3.addActionListener(this);
         miMusic4.addActionListener(this);
         miMusic5.addActionListener(this);
         miHelp.addActionListener(this);

         menuBar = new JMenuBar();
         menuBar.add(mnuOption);
         menuBar.add(mnuSet);
         menuBar.add(mnuHelp);
         this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource().equals(miHelp)){
            String str = "COMP2911\n";
            str +="Assignment3\n";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, str, "Help", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else if(e.getSource().equals(miExit)){
            System.exit(0);
        } else if(e.getSource().equals(btnReset)){
            System.out.println("reset the game");
        } else if(e.getSource().equals(btnBack)){
            System.out.println("get to the back stage");
        }
    }

    //game panel
    public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int[][] oriMap;
        private int[][] tempMap;

        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image mapimg[] = {
            kit.getImage("pic/0.png"),
            kit.getImage("pic/1.gif"),
            kit.getImage("pic/2.png"),
            kit.getImage("pic/3.png"),
            kit.getImage("pic/4.gif"),
            kit.getImage("pic/5.GIF"),
            kit.getImage("pic/6.GIF"),
            kit.getImage("pic/7.GIF"),
            kit.getImage("pic/8.GIF"),
            kit.getImage("pic/9.png")
        };
        public int[][] getOriMap() {
            return oriMap;
        }
        public void setOriMap(int[][] oriMap) {
            this.oriMap = oriMap;
        }
        public MyPanel(int[][] map){
            readMap(map);
            setSize(600,600);
            this.addKeyListener(this);
            //this.setFocusable(true);
        //  requestFocus();
        //  repaint();
        }
        public void readMap(int[][] map){
            this.oriMap = map;
            this.tempMap = map;
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println("2222222");

        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("1111111");
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("2333333333333");
        }


        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j< 15;j++){
                    g.drawImage(mapimg[this.tempMap[j][i]], i*30, j*30, 30,30,this);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Common problems with using `KeyListener` result from a) the component is not focusable b) the component does not have focus. 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 3) You should really test these things before getting to 250 lines of code! 4) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 5) Please use code formatting for code and code, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output. ..

Comment: .. To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Key bindings, key bindings, key bindings - Any answer which doesn't recommend using them is simply wrong

Comment: `KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus, so when you add a button to the UI, it grabs keyboard focus. As stated, the only correct answer would be to use the key bindings API

Answer (score -1):

Since you are adding `JPanel` and `JButton` to a `JFrame`, the `KeyListener` will only be active when the `JPanel` is focused. The `JPanel` gets unfocused when you press a button (and if you have multiple components from the start, it does not get focused automatically). You should add a `KeyListener` to the `JFrame` instead.

Comment: How is adding the `KeyListener` to the frame going to solve the problem when the button grabs keyboard focus. You've just moved the problem from one location to another without actually solving it

Comment: Becouse the JFrame contains the JButtons, the JFrame is focused when the JButtons are focused. A JFrame will always be focused as long as any of its components are focused. Basicly the JFrame will always be focused as long as the user is in that window. If you were the one downvoting me, can you please not downvote things you havent tried... @MadProgrammer

Comment: But the button gets keyboard focus, not the frame - that's not how KeyListeners work